# Множество переменных или один большой массив?

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d, переменные

Есть ли разница между использованием одного массива и множеством переменных для хранения данных? Или тут кому как удобнее?

Comment: Разница есть. Попробуйте отсортировать и потом отфильтровать хотя бы 10 переменных.

Comment: @tym32167 Допустим что у меня всего 30 переменных и мне не нужно их сортировать или фильтровать, переменные числовые и их значения зависят друг от друга и постоянно меняются. В плане потребления ресурсов есть разница? Или вопрос только в удобстве?

Comment: Вот чисто теоретически массивы - это reference type, т.е. CPU потенциально  потратит какое-то время на поиск этого массива в оперативной памяти. Однако это все теория, на практике эта разница нивелируется. Так что стоит отталкиваться от логических соображений.

Comment: с точки зрения производительности ваши 30 переменных будут точно также работать, если их поместить в массивы. Разница есть, но для 30 переменных она не существенная, а для миллиона переменных - никто столько не заводит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменна - отдельная единица информации несущая определенный контекст.
Массив - "коллекция" или объединение элементов или последовательность (зачастую по соображениям или умыслу) которые необходимо хранить либо рядом либо связанными в зависимости от решаемой задачи или использованию данных.

Теперь Вы можете Сами решить - если присутствует логика что данные как-то связаны (например показания датчика с временным интервалом, или данные для вывода  в столбец GUI) то наверное коллеция или массив лучшее решение для их хранения.

Если это отдельно взятые константы или magic числа или просто переменные (объединять в один массив данные о кол-ве использований чего-то и и числа которое можно использовать для вывода кода ошибки в которой поучаствовали злые силы 666) объединять в массив наверное смысла 0.

Answer (score 1):

Представим себе 1000 переменных типа Int(связанных логически между собой).

И представим себе массив на 1000 элементов.

---

1. массивом удобнее пользоватся. Ведь проще обращатся к любому элементу по индексу, чем запоминать названия 1000 переменных
2. массив оптимальнее расходует память (хотя с современными ресурсами это не проблема). Тебе не нужно хранить 1000 адресов памяти, тебе нужно запомнить 1 адрес памяти на первый элемент что бы обратится к любому элементу массива. Для того что бы обратится к 10тому элементу ты обращаешся к 1вому + сдвиг в памяти на 10 размеров Int.

Comment: Второй пункт конечно вдребезги разбивается, если говорить про ссылочные значения...

Comment: 2 пункт вообще спорный - даже если ресурсов много, их надо расходовать с умом. Да и посмотрите на gamedev, ресурсов тьма, а они каждый бит пытаются уместить в фрейм , чтобы у вас частота кадров была максимальной

Comment: @RiotBr3aker на тему того как хранятся ссылочные значения в массивах не в курсах. Задавался этим вопросом, но не гуглил. Если знаешь информацию - можешь поделится здесь в коментариях.

Comment: @Beeen007 геймдев это особенная сфера программирования где есть ряд своих особенностей. Например, ты не встретишь в геймдеве трай-кетчей ибо слишком ресурсоемки. Но это не значит что в других сферах программирования ты их не встретишь и это совсем не значит что их использование есть моветон.

Comment: @Andrew суть в том, что хоть ресурсы и в избытке, надо их экономить

Comment: @Beeen007 их надо экономить но без фанатизма. Оптимизация должна проходить тогда, когда она нужна. Оптимизация ради оптимизации - это плохой подход. Тогда уж на ассемблере писать нужно, а не на шарпе. Значительно оптимальнее по ресурсам выйдет ;) В средней ситуации читабельность и простота кода важнее оптимизации.

Comment: Да вообще пофиг на чем писать :) лучше Си все равно языка нет) остальное просто удобный инструмент